# How to find sum of list subsets with a recursive function Python

Tags: python, algorithm, list, recursion

I need to write a recursive function to return sums of all possible subsets.
I wrote the following code:

```
def subsets_sums(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        sum_list = [sum(lst)]
        for i in range(len(lst)):
            index_list = lst.copy()
            del index_list[i]
            test_list = subsets_sums(index_list)
            sum_list = test_list, sum_list
        return sum_list
```

But the output is very inelegant due to all the lists concatenations.
something like:

```
(((0, [10]), ((0, [3]), [13])), (((0, [10]), ((0, [6]), [16])), (((0, [3]), ((0, [6]), [9])), [19])))
```

for the list:

```
[10,3,6]
```

How can I make it appear in a list like:

```
[0,10,0,3,13,0,10,0,6,16,0,3,0,6,9,19]
```

Can I change something within the code?

Comment: Why does your output contain duplicates? The possible sums are 0, 10, 3, 6, 13, 16, 9, and 19.

Comment: can you add comments in the code

Answer (score 3):

The possible sums of `nums` are:

- `nums[0] + s` where `s` is a possible sum of `nums[1:]`, i.e. those including the first number.
- All the possible sums of `nums[1:]`, i.e. those not including the first number.

The base case of the recursion is that the empty list has only 0 as a possible sum. We'll use sets to avoid duplicates in the output; a sum is either possible or it isn't.

```py
def subset_sums(nums):
    if not nums:
        return {0}
    else:
        rest_sums = subset_sums(nums[1:])
        return { nums[0] + s for s in rest_sums } | rest_sums
```

Example:

```py
>>> subset_sums([10, 3, 6])
{0, 3, 6, 9, 10, 13, 16, 19}
```

Comment: OP did not ask for "all possible sums," they asked for "sums of all possible subsets."

Comment: What do you think the difference is? Are you saying there is a subset of `[10, 3, 6]` whose sum is not included in this output, or are you saying there is a number in this output which is not the sum of a possible subset?

Comment: OP provided this difference in the question description: "How can I make it appear in a list like: [0,10,0,3,13,0,10,0,6,16,0,3,0,6,9,19]"

Comment: That's weird, though. That list seems to be too long. As far as I know, there are only 2^n possible subsets.

Comment: Yes, that list is too long, and doesn't make sense in the context of the question. 3 is not the sum of two different subsets. The OP's algorithm is incorrect, not just because of the output format.

Comment: 3 is the sum of the subset, {3}, which is one of "all possible subsets."

Comment: Yes, and it is not the sum of any other subset; so it should not occur multiple times in the output.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and help.

Comment: Indeed there are multiple appearances of the numbers due to the nature of my recursion algorithm.
It might be not the most elegant one  (as I mentioned in the question) but it does what I need. Unfortunately, I was not able to understand@kaya3 algorithm fully  - but it sure does look more professional and elegant than mine.
I don't care much for the duplications any way because I know how to deal with them easily and the final list structure was my initial issue as I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

to get your desired output you can try:

```
lst = [10, 3, 6]
def subsets_sums(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return [0]
    else:
        sum_list = [sum(lst)]
        for i in range(len(lst)):
            index_list = lst.copy()
            del index_list[i]
            test_list = subsets_sums(index_list)
            sum_list = test_list + sum_list
        return sum_list
print(subsets_sums(lst))
```

output:

```
[0, 10, 0, 3, 13, 0, 10, 0, 6, 16, 0, 3, 0, 6, 9, 19]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that shows us all the possible subsets together with their sum including the empty set. By using an index to iterate over A, we avoid copying the list each time if we were to use the sublist operator `list[:]`.

```
def f(A, i=0):
  if i == len(A):
    return [([], 0)]

  rest = f(A, i + 1)

  return rest + [(s + [A[i]], _s + A[i]) for s, _s in rest]

print f([1, 2, 3])
```

Output:

```
[([], 0), ([3], 3), ([2], 2), ([3, 2], 5), ([1], 1), ([3, 1], 4), ([2, 1], 3), ([3, 2, 1], 6)]
```